# JQueryUI Datepicker - Adding Event to Disabled Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a JQueryUI Datepicker with some days disabled using the beforeShowDay parameter.  I know you can add a tooltip using that parameter, but I need to trigger a message to appear that says "This date may not be selected."

Is this even possible?  I've tried the onSelect parameter, but that only triggers when enabled dates are selected.  I've also tried giving the disabled dates a class and then adding a click event to items with that class, but it didn't seem to work either.

```
function unavailable(date) {
    var dmy = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, formattedDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, '', 'Unavailable'];
    }
}
$('#' + className).datepicker({
    controlType: 'select',
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    defaultDate: maxDate,
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
    setDate: maxDate,
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to trigger a custom `tool-tip`, throw an `alert` with a message or whatever here's an idea:

According to the documentation the second parameter is a CSS class:

> [1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default
>   presentation https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

So.. add a class for disabled days called "custom-tool-tip" or whatever and setup an event listener.

```
$('body').on('click', '.custom-tool-tip', function(e) { // or whatever event(s) you want to listen to
    alert('This date may not be selected.');
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  This worked.  I was trying to add the click event directly to items with the custom class, i.e.
$('.disabledDate').on('click', function .... )
but it wasn't working, I believe because there were no elements with that class on page load.  But I guess when doing $('body').on('click', CLASSNAME, etc, it sort of pre-emptively adds click events to any children of <body> with that classname?

Comment: Hi, good that it solved your issue.. if you consider this to have helped you please mark it as the correct answer. That way others with a similar issue may also benefit from it. And, yes.. that is what it does - that way you will be able to add e.g. eventListeners to dynamically added elements. It's not necessary to use  `body` though.. you may narrow it down to the closest parent element  - that way it might be more efficient.. and spot on.